# Optional word regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I trying to create a regex to extract **telephone**, **streetAddress**, **Pages** values (9440717256,H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony..) from the html page in python. These three fields are optional I tried this regex, but output is inconsistent

```
telephone\S+>(.+)</em>.*(?:streetAddress\S+(.+)</span>)?.*(?:pages\S+>(.+)</a></span>)?
```

**sample string**

```
<em phone="**telephone**">9440717256</em></div></div></li><li class="row"><i class="icon-sm icon-address"></i><div class="profile-details"><strong>Address</strong><div class="profi`enter code here`le-child"><address itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" class="data-item"><span itemprop="**streetAddress**">H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony</span>, <span>Vastu Colony, </span><span class="text-black" itemprop="addressLocality"><a href="/hyderabad/lal-bahadur-nagar/allcategory.aspx" title="**Pages**">Lal Bahadur Nagar</a></span>
```

Can anyone help me building the regex please ?

Comment: Please don't do this! [Terrible things](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) will happen.

Comment: You want an HTML parser and then go diving for the right fields.

Comment: @Tichodrama I've read that entire post and it actually says it's okay to use regex for html parsing as long as you're careful.

Comment: You read it in 40 seconds?

Comment: @Tichodrama Nope, 5.

Comment: @Shashank Then you should go ahead an answer the question using a regular expression. Have fun!

Comment: @Tichodrama On a more serious note, stop recommending HTML parsers as if they are a must have for every scraping problem. Even the author of your linked post would agree with me on this point.

Comment: @Shashank: The author of that post is a co-founder of Stack Exchange.  I submit that he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @Kevin I submit that he knows what he's talking about too. I'm actually *agreeing* with what he's talking about, at the end of his post. Which a lot of people seem to ignore.

Comment: @Shashank: What you're missing is the *middle* of his post, where he says that it's generally a Bad Idea to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: @Kevin How am I missing the middle? I'm not saying use regex for every scraping problem. I'm only asserting that you *don't* need to use an HTML parser for every scraping problem.

Comment: There is a big difference extracting a string of characters from a known context, and HTML parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that **your input is not valid HTML** and that it may be subject to change, you can use a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). **But** if your input changes, these simple selectors will have to be adapted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<em phone="**telephone**">9440717256</em></div></div></li><li class="row"><i class="icon-sm icon-address"></i><div class="profile-details"><strong>Address</strong><div class="profi`enter code here`le-child"><address itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" class="data-item"><span itemprop="**streetAddress**">H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony</span>, <span>Vastu Colony, </span><span class="text-black" itemprop="addressLocality"><a href="/hyderabad/lal-bahadur-nagar/allcategory.aspx" title="**Pages**">Lal Bahadur Nagar</a></span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
```

**Edit:** Since you now tell us that you want the *text* of the elements that have the specified *attribute value*, you can [use a function as filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

```
def find_phone(tag):
    return tag.has_attr("phone") and tag.get("phone") == "**telephone**"

def find_streetAddress(tag):
    return tag.has_attr("itemprop") and tag.get("itemprop") == "**streetAddress**"

def find_pages(tag):
    return tag.has_attr("title") and tag.get("title") == "**Pages**"


print(soup.find(find_phone).string)
print(soup.find(find_streetAddress).string)
print(soup.find(find_pages).string)
```

Output:

```
9440717256
H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony
Lal Bahadur Nagar
```

Comment: Despite my comments earlier, this is probably the best solution to the problem at hand. +1

Comment: It is always nice if at the end of a discussion agreement can be reached :)

Comment: @Tichodroma - Thanks, this look simple. can you let know how to get the values ( 9440717256, H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony..) instead of **telephone, **streetAddress**

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that we know what you really want?

Comment: @abhishekkurasala I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is safe to use in case you know the HTML provider, what the code inside looks like.

Then, just use alternations and named capture groups.

```
telephone[^>]*>(?P<Telephone>[^<]+)|streetAddress[^>]*>(?P<Address>[^<]+)|Pages[^>]*>(?P<Pages>[^<]+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK0lF7/5)

In case `>` is not serialized, you can use this regex (more universal one, **edit**: now, verbose):

```
telephone[^<]*>        # Looking for telephone
  (?P<Telephone>[^<]+) # Capture telephone (all text up to the next tag)
|
streetAddress[^<]*>    # Looking for streetAddress
  (?P<Address>[^<]+)   # Capture address (all text up to the next tag)
|
Pages[^<]*>            # Looking for Pages
  (?P<Pages>[^<]+)     # Capture Pages (all text up to the next tag)
```

[Sample demo on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wh44E7)

Pasting regex code part:

```
p = re.compile(ur'''telephone[^<]*>        # Looking for telephone
  (?P<Telephone>[^<]+) # Capture telephone (all text up to the next tag)
|
streetAddress[^<]*>    # Looking for streetAddress
  (?P<Address>[^<]+)   # Capture address (all text up to the next tag)
|
Pages[^<]*>            # Looking for Pages
  (?P<Pages>[^<]+)     # Capture Pages (all text up to the next tag)''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
test_str = "YOUR STRING"
print filter(None, [x.group("Telephone") for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)])
print filter(None, [x.group("Address") for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)])
print filter(None, [x.group("Pages") for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)])
```

Output (doubled results are the result of my duplicating the input string with different node order):

```
[u'9440717256', u'9440717256']
[u'H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony', u'H.No. 3-11-62, RTC Colony']
[u'Lal Bahadur Nagar', u'Lal Bahadur Nagar']
```

Comment: I can not see how a regular expression like this has any advantage over a HTML parser.

Comment: This regex, as it stands right now, is not *too* bad.  If you put it in verbose mode, added some comments and indentation, etc, it could be quite readable (though it is *not* readable in its one-line form).  The problem is when you find that it's "not quite right" because sometimes the HTML has an extra tag or something.  So you add a branch, or a group.  And tomorrow you add another.  It's all very benign, at first.  The road to hell is paved with good intentions.  Next week, you're testing your negative lookahead assertion with regex101.com.  Next month, your regex is recursive.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Please post your answer with an HTML parser. Then, we'll compare.

Comment: @Kevin: As I noted in the beginning of my answer, it is OK to use if you know what kind of HTML you get. If the code changes, attribute names change, you will need to modify your parser as well.

Comment: I would if the question would contain valid HTML. It doesn't. But me not providing an answer is not to be taken as proof that using a regex is a good idea.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Bah, just pass it through BeautifulSoup.  It'll probably work fine.